# MVC security WebSecurity.CreateAccount or Membership.CreateUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

---

Can anyone let me know the difference between

WebSecurity.CreateAccount or Membership.CreateUser

Which one should i use on creating an user in mvc 4 .net